# Choose/switch 'from' address in email from command-line

Tags: android, shell, android-intent, android-activity, adb

I am using this command to [send email from command-line](https://gist.github.com/adumont/8040008), It's able to send mails

```
am start -a android.intent.action.SEND -t "text/plain"
-c android.intent.category.DEFAULT 
-e to recipient@gmail.com 
-e android.intent.extra.SUBJECT Test 
-e android.intent.extra.TEXT "body" 
-n com.google.android.gm/.AutoSendActivity com.google.android.gm
```

But, unable to figure out, choosing/switching 'from' address, as my gmail app configured with multiple accounts.

Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

This is a really interesting question (something more original than many). Unfortunately my research seems to suggest that **this is not possible**.

An intent can accept a user param (`--user <USER_ID>`) however in my tests this would not work to change the sending account.

Assuming this is only for your own device, the only workaround-solution I came up with is to direct the intent to your own receiver which sends the email - [like this](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_(no_Intents)_in_Android)

If you are not hardcoding the 'from' and want to dynamically select a known account you can include an extra and have your receiver look up the correct account based on the extra

Comment: Thanks for answer @Nick.

I am not a android developer. 
Please let me know, how I can set up that java mail or point me a link which can help me

Comment: You might want to just check if the gmail app has direct intents you can do this with. It's likely it does. I don't have the time to spend on adding that information to my answer for a couple of days, sorry

Comment: Nick, That link is pointing .jar files. I don't know, how to install them. Please point me some steps. I will be awaiting for your time